# Should I use arrays or pointer if i want a user defined sizes

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

My question is simple if I have to input a data in an array with size user defined in C should I use pointers to store them or arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *arr, n, i;
    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter number of elements:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Enter number of elements:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
```

Personally I find it more comfortable to use pointers, but as C treats array and pointers differently I may face problems in the future.

Comment: Those two snippets work differently in how/where the arrays are allocated. With a large `n` the second one could end up overflowing the stack, breaking your code

Comment: Exactly that's one of the issue I may face later on as in the second one the array has to be declared after declaring n @UnholySheep

Comment: Also variable length arrays have become optional since C11 (they were mandatoy in C99) so the second snippet may not work on all compilers (e.g.: MSVC does not support VLAs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided snippets don't match in their semantics. The one using 'pointers' allocates memory on the heap using `malloc` the other one will allocate memory on the stack (using `alloca` under the hood).

---

Furthermore C does not treat pointers and arrays that differently:

```
    int a[10];
    a[2] = 69;
```

is semanticly identical to:

```
    int* a = alloca(10 * sizeof(int));
    *(a + 2) = 69;
```

Besides the `sizeof()` operator and how they are sometimes treated when passing them as parameters they are pretty much interchangeable.

So there is no real difference you can choose what you prefer.

---

And because you don't seem to know the difference between stack and heap:

Allocating memory on the stack has the advantages of:

- being faster
- less memory management

but:

- might overflow the stack when you allocate to much (~ 8kb)
- will stay allocated and take up system ressources until function goes out of scope

---

PS: you should always use `free()` when using `malloc()` even in examples

Answer (score 0):

The other huge difference that has been hinted at but not totally explained is the life time of those 2 arrays.

If this was a function to read a file and return an array of ints from it

```
int* ReadInts(){..}
```

The malloc one

```
int*ReadInts(){
     int * result = malloc(....);
     ...
     return result;
}
```

works fine, *but* the vla one does not

```
int*ReadInts(){
     int result[X];
     ...
     return result;
}
```

your compiler might compile it (maybe with a warning) but this is bad code. `result` will be released when ReadInts returns, so this is Undefined Behavior